# Move desktop item titles to the side?

Tags: customization

How can I move the titles of items on my desktop to the right side instead of the bottom like one can on OS X? Like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

In Nautilus (Files) your can change the default view via `Edit -> Preferences -> Views tab - Icon Views Default` and checking `Text beside icons`. Unfortunately, even with `Have file manager manage the desktop` set via `gnome-tweak-tool` (Advanced Settings) this doesn't change the desktop icons view, only for folder views within Nautilus.

Comment: I think this person is looking for a way to have it on the side for the desktop, not for the file browser like nautilus.